# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement get in requirement.text

Tags: python, heroku

I tried running `git push heroku master` in cmd but got the following error:

```
 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement get (from -r /tmp/build_8801ce40/requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: none)       

ERROR: No matching distribution found for get (from -r /tmp/build_8801ce40/requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
```

I have listed in my `requirements.txt` as below:

```
Flask==0.11.1
get
gunicorn==19.6.0
post
requests
wikipedia
line-bot-sdk
pandas==0.20.3
googletrans
```

What is the problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks to all, it has been fixed, I just need to delete get & post :((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `requirements.txt` should only contain modules that you need to install. `get` and `post` almost certainly don't belong here.

If you are doing something like

```
from requests import get
```

you'll need `requests` in your file. But you *don't* need `get`—it comes with `requests`. That's what the `from requests` part means.

Try editing your `requirements.txt` to something more like this:

```
Flask==0.11.1
gunicorn==19.6.0
requests
wikipedia
line-bot-sdk
pandas==0.20.3
googletrans
```

Then commit and redeploy.

A good way to make sure that your `requirements.txt` contains what it should is to use it in development, too. Add new dependencies directly to that file and then `pip install -r requirements.txt`. In this case, you would have caught the problem earlier.